# Oracle DBMS_FGA dynamically create an audit trail or policy

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, dynamic, plsql

my goal is to run a select to a table and based on the certain rows dynamically create an audit trail or policy on them.

so..

create a set_policy function that gets called/Looped:

```
 create or replace 
function set_policy
       ( sch VARCHAR2 ,
         tab VARCHAR2,
         colm VARCHAR2,
         pred VARCHAR2,
         emailer VARCHAR2
         )

 return VARCHAR2 is 

 policy_sql_stmt varchar2(1000);

 BEGIN         

           policy_sql_stmt :=
            'BEGIN
              SYS.DBMS_FGA.ADD_POLICY (
              object_schema => :s,
              object_name => :t,
              policy_name => ''CHK_:s_:t'',   
              audit_column => :c,
              audit_condition => :p,
              handler_schema => ''SYSADMIN_FGA'',
              handler_module => '''||emailer||'(:s,:t,''''CHK_:s_:t'''')'',   
              enable => TRUE,
              statement_types => ''SELECT, UPDATE'',
              audit_trail => SYS.DBMS_FGA.DB + SYS.DBMS_FGA.EXTENDED);
            END;';  

            --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('policy_sql_stmt = :' || policy_sql_stmt);

            BEGIN
                EXECUTE IMMEDIATE policy_sql_stmt USING sch,tab,colm,pred;
                --EXECUTE IMMEDIATE policy_sql_stmt USING pred;

                EXCEPTION  
                        WHEN OTHERS THEN
                        BEGIN
                          --dbms_output.put_line('set_policy error code: '||SQLCODE);
                          --dbms_output.put_line(DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_CALL_STACK);
                          RETURN ('set_policy error code: '||SQLCODE);
                        END;
             END;
             RETURN 'success';
   END;
```

Then a procedure that calls the function...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE audit_slac_tables
AS
  --DECLARE
  emailer   VARCHAR2(40):='audit_email_alert';
  isSuccess VARCHAR2(40);
  CURSOR myCursor
  IS
    SELECT SCHEMA   AS sch,
      TABLE_NAME    AS tab,
      FILTER_COLUMN AS colm,
      WHERE_COND    AS pred
    FROM SLAC_REDACTION_TABLE slac;
    --WHERE slac.table_name IN ('RECIPIENT','CARD');
BEGIN
  FOR curRec IN myCursor
  LOOP
    BEGIN
            --emailer := getEmailer(curRec.sch ,curRec.tab);
            isSuccess := set_policy(curRec.sch ,curRec.tab, curRec.colm, curRec.pred, emailer);
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Proc isSuccess = :' || isSuccess);
          EXCEPTION
          WHEN OTHERS THEN
            dbms_output.put_line('Proc error code: '||SQLCODE);
            dbms_output.put_line('Proc error msg: '||SQLERRM);
            --dbms_output.put_line(DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_CALL_STACK);
            --dbms_output.put_line('================================================');
            CONTINUE;
    END;
    --dbms_output.put_line('================================================');
  END LOOP;
  COMMIT;
END audit_slac_tables;
```

if I call it...

```
exec AUDIT_SLAC_TABLES;
```

I get the following bewildering error

Error starting at line : 6 in command -
exec AUDIT_SLAC_TABLES
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 12, column 18:
PLS-00201: identifier 'SYS.DBMS_FGA' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 2, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06512: at "GAPLITE.SET_POLICY", line 51
ORA-06512: at "GAPLITE.AUDIT_SLAC_TABLES", line 27
ORA-06512: at line 1
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Why a reference problem where the script DBMS_FGA.ADD_POLICY never had a problem?

I can run this script ( listed 1st above ) but not dynamically... it loses trhe contextual reference to the SYS packages somehow ??

Comment: You need to have a corresponding value in the USING statement for each and every bind variable.  You have 10 bind variables in your SQL, but only 4 values in the USING clause.  Also, you'll need to do some concatenation to get the values correct as they won't substitute the way you have it.  Like ''CHK_''||:s||''_''||:t||''....   (you'll need to work out the correct quotations).

Comment: Also, you may need to check access.  Your access via script is different than via compiled PL/SQL.  The PL/SQL schema needs to have a direct grant as opposed to you maybe having access via a role grant.

Comment: @unleashed Yes I've updated the statements.. the key issue here was that I was assuming the user had implicit privileges on the sys.dbms_fga package, it was not the case... so I needed to    Connect sys/xxx
Grant execute on sys.dbms_fga to   <username>;